# Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.set_Method(System.String)'

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I was doing some Sharepoint operations using [Microsoft.Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.graph?view=graph-core-dotnet), Let's take the example of listing the active users. consider the following snippets that I'm using:

```
public async Task<IList<User>> GetUsers()
{
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = await GetGraphServiceClient();
    var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
    return users;
}
```

Where the `GetGraphServiceClient` method creates an instance of the `Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient` which is defined like the following:

```
public async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphServiceClient()
{
    return new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
    {
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await GetAccessToken());

    }));
}
```

I'm getting a valid access token, but the line `await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();` throws an error, which says

> Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.set_Method(System.String)'.

Stack trace

> at Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceUsersCollectionRequest.d__4.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
> at Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceUsersCollectionRequest.GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceUsersCollectionRequest.GetAsync()
> at myNamespace.GraphAPIHelper.d__3.MoveNext()

Here are the versions of the graphSDK and SharePoint client used in the project :

[image]

Can someone help me to identify what is causing the issue? I have cross-checked and verified the tenant-ID, clientId, and access tokens. something is missing but not getting any clue.

Answer (score 2):

Today I ran into a similar situation. I don't use Sharepoint, but wanted to use Graph to find a user and got the error message `Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.set_Method(System.String)'.` Lucky for me, I was in the position to debug another solution where almost the exact code for querying users actually works. By comparing two solutions, I finally found a discrepancy in the list of nuget packages. The faulty solution had a reference to  Microsoft.Graph.Core and Microsoft.Graph. The working solution only referenced Microsoft.Graph. Removing the reference to Microsoft.Graph.Core fixed the problem for me. Don't ask me why though.

Answer (score 0):

For me works downgrade to 1.25.1 version of Microsoft.Graph.Core to solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You have to change Core version to 1.**

Comment: can you add more details, please?